# Network Change Control & Compliance

Tags: networking, cisco, monitoring

I'm looking for a network change management & compliance audit tool, I know that SolarWinds and tufin are very know.

Do you have any experience that you can share regarding these two or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've deployed NetMRI for this at a large enterprise (100s of networking devices):

http://www.infoblox.com/en/products/netmri.html

It was awe inspiring what it would detect and the policy manager in it was very very powerful.  The learning curve on it was a bit steep, but once you set it up, it alerted us about problems before they would affect users and the reporting it did about network status made executives very happy.